# Add to cart function not working for first product when cart is empty

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using { WC()->cart->add_to_cart($new_post_id) ;} to add a product ,but this function does not adding for the first time when cart is empty.If I add product using default add to cart button, Then after the above function works properly so can you please point out the issue . Basically session cookiees are not created with while adding via function but if the session cookkie is set then this works smoothly . can you guide me how to set these cookies in my case .

[console Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5RJk.png)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the quantity is missing of the product.
Try to use

```
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($new_post_id,quantity);
```

hope this will help you.

Comment: I have used it already but does not works basically I am having issues with WC()->cart->set_cart_cookies(); The session are not set , If they are set already then this works fine .

Comment: @owt have you found the solution? then please help me i have also face same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add following code to init hook:

```
if (!is_user_logged_in() && !is_admin()) {
  if (class_exists('WooCommerce')) {
     $woocommerce = WC();
     if ($woocommerce) {
         $session = $woocommerce->session;
         if ($session) {
               $session->set_customer_session_cookie(true);
           }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works and what makes it different from the other answers given. You can find out more at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page.